# Jquery in MVC ...IndexOf not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery function in my ASP.NET MVC project.

Why does `IndexOf` not work in my function?

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.10.2.js" />
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#finpost').keyup(function () 
    {
        $("#CityId > option").each(function () {
            var t = this.text.toUpperCase();
            alert(t.IndexOf('2200'));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `indexOf()` - lower case `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is a case sensitive language.

Use `alert(t.indexOf('2200'));` instead of `alert(t.IndexOf('2200'));`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is case sensitive language, it should be "indexOf" with small 'i'. You're using "IndexOf" with capital 'I'.